# Finding qualified names that reference a given object

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, garbage-collection, introspection

For debugging purposes, we want to obtain all the names under which a given object is known; I want qualified names (i.e., `A.x` rather than `x`). Here's our first attempt:

```
import gc, sys
def find_names(obj):
    result = []
    for referrer in gc.get_referrers(obj):
        if isinstance(referrer, dict):
            for k in referrer:
                if referrer[k] is obj:
                    n = '???'
                    for f in ('__qualname__', '__name__'):
                        if f in referrer:
                            n = referrer[f]
                    result.append('{}.{}'.format(n, k))
    return ','.join(result)
```

The problem is I cannot find the "name" of the container from the container itself unless the container is `__dict__` of a class or a module (then `__qualname__` or `__name__` work). I don't know why `__class__` is not part of an instance's `__dict__` (is it stored in slots?), but the reason doesn't matter - what matters is I can't get it.

Is there anything I can do for this to work as follows:

```
class A:
    pass
a = A()
a.x = object()
find_names(a.x) # I want this to return `a.x` rather than `???.x`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do it by checking the referrers of any referrer that corresponds to an instance, and looking for the one whose `__dict__` is identical to the original referrer:

```
def find_names(obj):
    result = []
    for referrer in gc.get_referrers(obj):
        if isinstance(referrer, dict):
            for k in referrer:
                if referrer[k] is obj:
                    n = '???'
                    for f in ('__qualname__', '__name__'):
                        if f in referrer:
                            n = referrer[f]
                            break
                    if n == '???':
                        parents = gc.get_referrers(referrer)
                        for p in parents:
                            if getattr(p, '__dict__', None) is referrer:
                                n = '<instance of class ' + p.__class__.__name__ + '>'
                    result.append(str(n) + '.' + str(k))
    return '\n'.join(sorted(result))
```